How to fix Bad Gateway error after API calls of app running in Docker Container (nginx server, windows)?
I have just run an app consisting of MongoDB, a REST API and a web app running with nginx with Docker (docker-compose, webapp is at port 8888:80, but the following problem also occured on 80:80). Without Docker the communication between all those pieces worked perfectly, now every time, when requests to the API are made, the response is "Bad Gateway (502)". I guess it has to do with my nginx.conf or Dockerfile of the webapp, but I'm not sure. Attached is the code.
Does somebody have a solution? For interest I'm on windows.
EDIT:
I now changed "localhost:8080" to "service:8080" cause the service is basically my API, but now I get an internal server error (500).
EDIT 2:
The connection string of my backend app to the database had a syntax error. Everything works fine now.
My nginx.conf:
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        location / {
            include mime.types;
            root html;
            index start.html;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #    root html;
        #}
        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
}

My Dockerfile:
FROM nginx:1.26.1
COPY ./html /etc/nginx/html
COPY ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

